# CPP reading 0x0A as string instead of hexadecimal

Tags: c++, type-conversion, hex

I am fetching some values from database these are comma separated hexadecimal values(0x0A,0x01,0X0B). I fetch them explode them by comma but when trying to use 0X0A as hexadecimal value it treat it as string not hexadecimal number I want to typecast it in hexadecimal.

Comment: use strtoul to convert the string to a number

Comment: Ben I do not need to convert string from 0A to 0x0A it already 0x0A i just want CPP to read it as a hexadecimalvalue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `istringstream` with `std::hex` to convert hex strings to numeric values:

```
std::istringstream stream("0x0A");
int val = 0;
stream >> std::hex >> val;
std::cout >> val; // prints "10"
```